# Angular 5 URL route params with url encoding showing &3F instead of?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-routing, angular-router

My angular 5 app is database driven from an old system and it is spitting out the url encoding for ? which is %3F

So when I click on link

```
http://localhost:4200/inquiry%3FUserID%3D61525%26AppID%3D15%26AppGroupID%3D116%26SelectedCaseID%3D0%26SelectedRoleID%3D0
```

because the Route is

```
 { path: 'inquiry', component: InquiryComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

It goes then to  `http://localhost:4200/`

All because of this database --> stored proc to web api to my angular codebase ...

I have thought about some options

1. I don't know how to change `%3F` to `?` in the route  ..
2. The OnInit in the route component file doesn't seem to want to run
3. I was thinking about how could i in my ngfor use an ngif to do some sort of replace on the url if it find %3F convert it to ?
4. Route evaluation?
5. anything else?

Essentially I need the URL to be

```
http://localhost:4200/inquiry?UserID%3D61525%26AppID%3D15%26AppGroupID%3D116%26SelectedCaseID%3D0%26SelectedRoleID%3D0=
```

Notice  `inquiry?` instead of `inquiry%3F`

Comment: so how are you getting now?

Comment: please elaborate your post i m confused

Comment: You're looking for `.replace()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: how do i use replace() in typescript / angular